# Angular-UI router: set arbitrary GET parameters in route

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Is it possible to set arbitrary optional parameters in a URL using angularjs and angular-ui-router?

I think I know how to extract parameters (`$stateParam.parameter`), but how can I set them when navigating from one route to another? Simply calling `$state.go(newState, {param1: 'foo', param2: 'bar'})` doesn't seem to work (at least the url doesn't contain `?param1=foo&param2=bar` in this case). I don't want to define the parameters beforehand as part of the state definition. I'd like them to be populated by the user.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#query-parameters) you can append `?` to the url. You can then name each query parameter resulting in something like this: `/go-to?param1=hello&param2=world`. This is a good read on the subject: [link](http://benfoster.io/blog/ui-router-optional-parameters)

Furthermore, if you want completely arbitrary parameters you should use `$location.search()` instead of $stateParams. ([Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location))

Example of getting/setting GET parameters by using `$location.search()`:

```
// given url http://example.com/#/some/path?foo=bar&baz=xoxo
var searchObject = $location.search();
// => {foo: 'bar', baz: 'xoxo'}

// set foo to 'yipee'
$location.search('foo', 'yipee');
// $location.search() => {foo: 'yipee', baz: 'xoxo'}
```

Comment: Appending `?` requires to define a parameter which I can't do. `$location.search()` does only alter the URL, but doesn't actually trigger a reload. Triggering a manual `$state.reload()` wipes the query parameter that I set with `$location.search('foo', 'bar')`.

Comment: `$location.search('foo', 'yipee')` only does a reload when you define `foo` in your url (`?foo`).